# many-to-many in grails is not saving records in the relationship table

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

I've got a many-to-many association between `Color` and `Shade`. `Color` has many shades and `Shades` has many colors.

I've modeled this like so:

```
class Color {
  static hasMany = [shades: Shade]
  String name
}

class Shade {
  static belongsTo = Color
  static hasMany = [colors: Color]
  String name
}
```

However, when I run the following code:

```
new Color(name: "Red").addToShades(new Shade(name: "light")).save()
```

It only saves record in `Color` table and `Shade` table but not in `Color_Shades` table which is essentially a join table between the two.

Am I doing something wrong? Thats how I understood it from the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your table isn't populated, but there's an advise of Burt in [this talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) about the performance using this type of many-to-many. The solution is to use an intermediate class:

```
class ColorShade implements Serializable {

  Color color

  Shade shade

  //implement hashcode & equals!
  //and also implement helpers like removeAll, remove, create and get.

  static mapping = {
    id composite: ['color','shade']
    table 'Color_Shades'
    version false
  }
}
```

You can see a example class in the [Spring Security Core plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/templates/PersonAuthority.groovy.template).

Comment: How would I save the relationship with this?

Comment: Look at the `static create()` in the spring security link. Implement something similar and call `ColorShade.create(colorInstance, shadeInstance)`.